# When to use is and has been in an English sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the meaning and reason for using *has been* in the sentence below?

> In the past few weeks, the highest fresh stock that [the] hospital has received **has been** 7000 injections.

Is it correct if we use "....has received **is** 7000 injections"?

Comment: A present perfect action can have direct object...

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. The "has been" version suggests this may change -- the hospital may receive a greater fresh stock. With "is", it's just a fact.